# How to warp a sector like area of an image into another sector like area using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to achieve, very crudely speaking, a stretching of borders of this shape: [image: Shape]

All parameters (r,theta,delta(r), delta(theta)) can vary.

I've tried using `fitgeotrans`, `projective2d`and `affine2d` but they seem to work mostly for polygonal shapes.

Is it at all possible to use a polar coordinated image (using `cart2pol`) and then give polar points to `fitgeotrans`? Or is a polygon encapsulating the sector area the only option?

Comment: You can always do the warp yourself...

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should do a *back-warp*. This means for each pixel in the *`dst`* image, find the corresponding pixel in the `src` and copy it there.

You could use `pol2cart` to do this, but it seems a little forced, since you have to do the adjustment yourself anyway.

Comment: But i don't have the dst image ( I only have its boundary)...I need to get it by warping the src such that the boundary of the src warps into the boundary of the dst...with all other pts warped accordingly

Comment: You need the *pixel coordinates* of the dst image. Not the pixel values. Just go over each pixel in the dst image (or bounding box), convert them to (1) dst-polar, then convert to (2) src polar then to src Cartesian. Use the src pixel color (with the interpolation of you choice) as the dst pixel value.